# Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to push to Heroku and my deploy shows as successful but when I look at the app it says:

```
 Application error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

When I look at the log the only thing I could find that might be causeing the problem is

```
  Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
```

I have followed the steps from the heroku docs to precompile my assets with  rake assets:precompile before pushing to heroku but in the log I never get the message:

```
-----> Preparing Rails asset pipeline
```

I am not sure what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Did you commit the sprockets manifest file? i.e, does `$ ls public` list the manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

try running `rake assets:clobber` before you deploy